# Django MVT: Кто должен обновлять данные на странице?

Tags: django, веб-программирование

Только начал изучать `backend` + поверхностно фронт для целостной картины. Возник вопрос обновления данных на странице.

Допустим есть таблица, которая выводит какую-то `data`. В результате выбора категории пользователем, фронту необходимы новые данные для таблицы. Кто отвечает за их обновление? Понятно, что фронт должен отправить запрос бэку, что ему нужна `data`.

Но в ответ бэк должен кинуть html или json, который должен "распаковать" фронт?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря, что Вы хотите. Если хотите обновить данные без перезагрузки страницы тогда сервер должен отправлять JSON. А если с перезагрузкой страницы тогда HTML.